# Receiving F2 Key Gesture and click on background of treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, treeview, treeviewitem

So I have finally implemented a project for editing text in WPF as overlay of a TreeViewItem:

https://fsc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#InplaceEditBoxLib/README.md

See Rename or New Folder function in folder browser of demo project: FileListViewTest
https://fsc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Folder%20View&referringTitle=Documentation

...but I cannot seem to find a solution for pressing that F2 Key to initialize renaming. I have searched and tried different solutions but could not find one that applies to my scenario. Can someone help me with this please? Please tell me a specific solution to my specific implementation. The project is very well documented, the folder view is implemented here:

https://fsc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#FolderBrowser/FolderBrowser/Views/FolderBrowserView.xaml

I am having the same problem with canceling the edit mode via click on the background of the treeview. Does someone know how I could do that?

Comment: Normally what you need is to hook up the key stroke and check if it is F2 to run some appropriate code. However WPF has the so-called ***InputBinding*** including ***MouseBinding*** and ***KeyBinding***. Each `UIElement` has a `InputBindings` collection, so you can add a `KeyBinding` to `F2` there. The code run is specified by a `Command` as part of `KeyBinding`.

Comment: Aehm, thanks for your hint. But could you be more specific please - I have really searched a lot before coming here to ask this question it would be great if could tell me more precisely what I have to do. I don't understand where **there** is in : "so you can add a KeyBinding to F2 there." and how this relates to a treeviewitem?

Comment: @King King
I have tried this:
`
              <EditInPlace:EditBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="F2"
                            Command="{Binding Path=Data.StartRenameCommand, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                </KeyBinding>
              </EditInPlace:EditBox.InputBindings>
            </EditInPlace:EditBox>
`

but to no avail please help me finding a solution that does work :-)